# Flash player for RTSP H264

Tags: flash, actionscript, web, rtsp

Is it real to play video stream using RTSP protocol encoded with h.264 codec??

I need to create webapp for streaming video from IP-camera, or it will be easyer if I include for example VLC plugin in my web-page and use it for playing??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No its not currently possible in Flash, unless you write your own RTSP protocol client in AS3 using Sockets.

You can embed VLC in a web page, using [VLC WebPlugin](http://wiki.videolan.org/Documentation%3aWebPlugin). You need to know JavaScript to use that.

Answer (score 0):

See https://github.com/AxisCommunications/locomote-video-player.  VLC's NPAPI player worked great until Chrome deprecated NPAPI plugins.  By Sept 2015 they will apparently be removed from Chrome altogether [[1](https://www.chromium.org/developers/npapi-deprecation)].